# Disabling scrollview so touchesMoved can work?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

How do I disable the scrollview so that I can use touchesMoved until I activate scrollview again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yourScrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;